# .htaccess - no PHP error or no write file permission

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

server Apache, 
PHP 5.4

I have default .htaccess on my hosting with:

```
<FilesMatch "\.php$"> # phpvs v6
AddHandler x-httpd-php6 .php # phpvs v6
</FilesMatch> # phpvs v6
```

but there is no errors display in PHP file, but allow me to create files by PHP scripts.
When I delete this 3 lines and put

```
php_flag display_errors on
php_flag html_errors on
php_flag  log_errors on
```

errors displays but I can not use fopen or any to create files. I get:

```
Warning: fopen(newfile.txt) [function.fopen]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/desdde/domains/xXXXXx/public_html/index.php on line 2
Unable to open file!
```

Is there any possibility to merge:

```
<FilesMatch "\.php$"> # phpvs v6
AddHandler x-httpd-php6 .php # phpvs v6
</FilesMatch> # phpvs v6
```

and

```
php_flag display_errors on
php_flag html_errors on
php_flag  log_errors on
```

to working together?

I have tried sth like this:

```
<?php
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
asdasd
require('simple_html_dom.php');
?>
```

but this not display errors. When I comment reguire line, it shows error. I don't know why it doesn't work with this require.

Comment: Use error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE); to report simple errors

Comment: what is the code you try to create the file with?

Comment: Are you sure your current working directory as seen by the script is a writable one?

Comment: I can write file by PHP script but only with original .htaccess:
<FilesMatch "\.php$"> # phpvs v6
AddHandler x-httpd-php6 .php # phpvs v6
</FilesMatch> # phpvs v6

Comment: Most probably without AddHandler you are using older version of PHP configured as mod_php Apache module, which may be configured differently and select different working directory (Apache's mod_vhost is known not to set it up properly). Try something like `fopen(dirname(__FILE__).'/test.txt')` to be sure you are writing relatively to your current script location. Just keep in mind this trick it may not work after encoding with some versions of IONCube or Zend optimizer (sorry, I don't remember which anymore), that messes up `__FILE__` special constant.

Comment: If a posted answer worked for you, don't edit that into your answer. Consider clicking the checkbox next to the answer that helped you to mark it as accepted instead. http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/244731

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PHP 5.3 and up you may use `.user.ini` files to customize PHP. I guess `AddHandler ...` allows to select newer PHP version, probably working via CGI/FCGI interface. Thats why `php_flag ...` directives aren't working anymore. Unfortunately `.user.ini` files may be blocked by your server administrator. Check `user_ini.filename` in `phpinfo()` with `AddHander...` section enabled. If it's not empty, you may use filename given there as your custom configuration. If it has its default value of `.user.ini` you may create such file in the same directory as your scripts or on any level up and override selected settings, like:

```
display_errors=on
html_errors=on
log_errors=on
```

Just keep in mind, that PHP may cache information found there, so current processes handling requests need to time out before the file change will be catched (at least that's what's written in documentation comments, I haven't experienced it personally). For more info take a look at: http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.per-user.php

Comment: I have there:
    user_ini.filename .user.ini